Printer installation issue with ubuntu 22.04
I have canon ir1643 ii MFP which I am using with ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Some time the printer works properly and some time not. Some time the same printer gets installed with different name like **@localhost. I am getting so much trouble using this printer with ubuntu 22.04. I have connected the printer via. USB cable and installed the canon driver downloaded from canon website.
I am writing this issue with the hope that someone with help me resolving these issues.
Looking forward for an solution from the community.
Thank you

Have you installed any printer driver software from Canon? Or have you configured the printer by selecting from the list of available printers? Or are you using the printer setup that was automatically installed? Edit your question with the details of the steps you have taken.

Multifunctional device / Printer / Scanner Installation Troubleshooting
Connecting the device via USB port

If the device is connected to USB and LAN ports at the same time,
disconnect it from the LAN port and reboot your system
If the device driver is not installed, install it. Then reboot the
system
If the problem persists, Try connecting the device to a different USB
port. For example, to a USB 3.0 port. It is possible that the
Universal Serial Bus Host Controller is not working properly
If the problem is not resolved, configure the CUPS print server via
Web Interface. By default, the web interface is available at
http://localhost:631/admin. To login use your username and password.
For more information see Install and configure a CUPS print
server
If the device still does not work properly, try using a different
driver version.

Connecting the device via LAN port

If the device is connected to USB and LAN ports at the same time,
disconnect it from the USB port and reboot your system
If necessary, install the device driver. Then reboot the system
If the problem persists, check the involved LAN devices and firewall
If the problem is not resolved, configure the CUPS print server via
Web Interface
If the device still does not work properly, try using a different
driver version.



Note: If the Simple Scan Utility doesn't suit you, try using the XSane featureful graphical frontend.
